# Access asp.net page from a code behind class

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, page-lifecycle

This is for academic purposes, please no responses of "why would you want to do that"

If I have a page called Home.aspx and it has a code behind Home.aspx.cs.

In Home.aspx.cs I have some public properties, e.g.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I have another page called Error.aspx

Can I create an instance of Home.aspx.cs from within Error.aspx.cs and access the Name property? And if not, why not.

Comment: I'm not asking why..:) I am asking _what_ are you trying to do. What is the problem you are trying to solve and maybe we can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I had come across some sloppy code that had public variables in a code behind and I wanted to see if another sloppy developer would be able to create/grab an instance of the Home class and set/change variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create an instance of Home.aspx.cs from within Error.aspx.cs and
>   access the Name property? And if not, why not.

Yes, you can...

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create an instance of Home.aspx.cs from within Error.aspx.cs and access the Name property?

Yes you can *create an instance*, like any other object. You can do:

```
Home h = new Home();
h.Name = "Hello;
```

But it's a ***new instance***, it doesn't have user-speicifc data inside... In other words: 
It's not an instance of a "real" page that a user saw

I'm guessing your next question will be - *If I get to the `Error` page from the `Home` page, can I access the properties?* and the simple answer will be no.

If you want to pass data between pages, you should use the **[Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** object, **[Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**,  or other similar concepts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a value from a control on the Home page after the user has been redirected to the Error page, you can also try using the PreviousPage.FindControl() method...

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("SomeText");
```

OR

```
string str = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("SomeText").Text;
```

where "SomeText" is the ID value of the control you want to read from.